# Can someone please explain what conf is in processing/java and what its uses are?

Tags: java

I'm making a game using java in processing thats like space invaders, I was having a look around for help with a few issues I'm having and found a set of code that is using Conf, I have no idea what it is and google searches seem to be coming up blank. I can tell it's a built in method because it has to be called at the top and initialized. What is it and why is it used in java/processing??

It's to be found in this coding: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/6572

It's literally used constantly throughout so I'm really curious to have the concept explained to me, sorry if this is a very simple question but I cant find anything online

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the full source code](https://github.com/TristanBrismontier/Processing_SpaceInv) for the application you will see that Conf is simply one of the Java classes defined in the application: https://github.com/TristanBrismontier/Processing_SpaceInv/blob/master/SpaceInvader/src/Conf.java

In Java (as in all programming languages I'm aware of) a program is usually comprised of more than one class file. The use of the Conf class in the code you were looking at is how you reference and make use of one Java class from another Java class.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the source code you linked to:

```
class Conf {
  boolean Ri, Le, Ti;
  int lives;
  int score;


  Conf() {
    Ri = false;
    Le = false;
    Ti = false;
    lives = 3;
    score = 0;

  }
}
```

So it seems to be an object holding the state of the game (number of lives, score, and three other horribly named fields)

Answer (score 1):

Conf is a class for storing the number of current lives,  score and the state of the input keys (left/right/space pressed/released). It is created in the code you linked to (you have to scroll down a little),  and is nothing built-in for java/processing. Hope that helps.

Comment: If its nothing built in then why in the void setup() does the person call it at the top like Conf conf; and then later on does conf = new Conf(); I thought that would mean it was a built in method?

Comment: @TheJordyluke That does not mean it is a built in method. Not sure why you would think that. They are just defining a class member of type Conf and then later initializing it.